# Using different ssh config options based on port

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a situation where I have to use different login credentials on the same IP address based on the port the I use.

So and example on the command line would look like this:

```
ssh user1@192.168.1.2:22
```

and

```
ssh user2@192.168.1.2:2222
```

I have setup the following in my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
 Host "192.168.1.*"
   user user1
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_user1
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

which works great for the user1 at port 22 scenario but is there a way to setup an alternate user and IdetityFile for user2 at port 2222?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess I should have kept searching....

[SSH config host match port](https://superuser.com/questions/838898/ssh-config-host-match-port?rq=1) over on superuser.com had the answer I needed!

Basically instead of:

```
Host "192.168.1.*"
```

I'm now using:

```
Match host "192.168.1.*" exec "test %p = 22"
```

and

```
Match host "192.168.1.*" exec "test %p = 2222"
```

Comment: Hmm ... interesting - didn't realize you could shell out like that.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't try it out, but I think the HostName option (see `man ssh_config` could provide you a solution:

```
 Host "host22"
   Hostname "192.168.1.2"
   Port 22
   user user1
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_user1
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
 Host "host2222"
   Hostname "192.168.1.2"
   Port 2222
   user user2
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_user2
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

With this you should be able to do:

```
ssh user1@host22
ssh user2@host2222
```

or even

```
ssh host22
ssh host2222
```

as the user name and the port are given in the config file.

Comment: That would have worked but I have an essentially infinite number of servers that I need to do this with so I didn't want to have to create a new config file entry for each one.